# How to check whether a set of statements is consistent

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

When do you call a system is consistent?

Here's the system (it's consistent btw)

> When a software is upgraded, user can't use the software
>
> If user can use the software, user can save their file
>
> If user can save their file, user can't upgrade the software

Comment: so you just need a SINGLE set of interpretations which makes all formulas true? In a sense, not unsatisfiable?

Comment: For the particular set of statements you're quoting there, I'm wondering whether the relevant question is really "is this set of three statements consistent?" It looks looks more likely that the person who originally wrote them down had in mind to ask, "is the third statement a valid conclusion from the two others?"

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

A system [theory, set of sentences] is [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency)

> "if and only if it has a model, i.e., there exists an interpretation under which all formulas in the theory are true."

How to check if a set of sentences is consistent ? Try to find an interpretation under which all formulas in it are true.

---

The *logical form* of the argument is :

> if Grade, then not-Use:
>
> if Use, then Save:
>
> > Therefore, if Save, then not-Grade.

We can use this for checking both *consistency* [i.e. *satisfiability*] and *validity*.